# How to sequence multiple observables

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular2 and front-end development in general, so my apologies if I'm missing the obvious answer.

I'm working on an Angular2 app.  I'm not sure about the best way to accomplish a task in a component I'm working on.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("init component");
    console.log(this.activatedRoute);

    this.paramSub = this.activatedRoute.params.switchMap(
        (params: Params) => this.personSearchService.getPerson(params['personId']))
        .subscribe(result => this.personDetails = result);

    this.orgSub = this.personSearchService.getPersonFedOrgs(0).subscribe(
        results => this.orgs = results,
        error => console.log(error)
    );

    //pseudo-code
    watch this.orgs and this.personDetails
        if change
            do logic
}
```

During the OnInit lifecyle hook, I do two things, I get and use a route parameter with a service and I also get a list of organizations from a second service.  All of that's working fine.

The section I've labeled as psuedo-code is functionality I want to add.  I want to take the results of the first two service calls and execute some business logic.

I know that I can't directly use this.personDetails and this.orgs because they'll be undefined (until the async calls are resolved).  So I think I need to wrap them in an Observable so that I can execute some logic each time they're updated.  But I'm not exactly sure how to do that.  Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cobmineLatest()` operator. I refactored the code a bit for readability:

```ts
personDetails$ = this.activatedRoute.params
  .map((params: Params) => params['personId'])
  .switchMap(id => this.personSearchService.getPerson(id))

orgs$ = this.personSearchService.getPersonFedOrgs(0)

Observable.combineLatest(personDetails$, orgs$)
  .subscribe(([details, orgs]) => {
    console.log(details, orgs);
  })
```

Don't forget to import operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

CombineLatest does the job , except , it would emit a value if either of the streams has emitted any value , so you can't be sure that you get notified when both of them have actually emitted values .

For this , you need to zip them :d

```
    this.paramSub = this.activatedRoute.params.switchMap(
        (params: Params) => this.personSearchService.getPerson(params['personId']));

    this.orgSub = this.personSearchService.getPersonFedOrgs(0)


Observable.zip(this.paramSub, this.orgSub)
  .subscribe(result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
```

Comment: I found this description of zip: [link]http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Comment: Can't seem to edit my comment, so here's the full comment I had meant to type.

I found this description of zip: [link]http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html  

It seems like combineLatest would wait until both observers have emitted a value and then it emits another value when either changes.  

Where as zip only emits a new value after both observers have changed.  Is that a correct assessment?