# How to resolve multiple Observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have 2 (or more) Observables returned from services, each of them only returning one value (think `Observable.just()`). Each of them is of different type (I'm writing in TypeScript so types matter).

Is there a way to know when all Observables resolved (using promises terminology) either successfully or failed, I need to be able to handle failures individually, and carry on.

contrived example:

```
const obs1  = someService.getThisThing(); //Observable<Type1>
const obs2  = someService.getAnotherThing(); //Observable<Type2>

const someObj = {};

obs1.subscribe(v1 => someObj.v1 = v1);
obs2.subscribe(v2 => someObj.v2 = v2);

// call someFunc(someObj), only when both above observables resolved to a value
someFunc(someObj);
```

I have tried using `merge` but then I loose type safety as values may come in any order, and I have to inspect their type in `.subscribe` to determine which is which

I have tried `combine` and `combineLatest` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250453/how-to-sequence-multiple-observables) - but then they both resolve at the same time, and if 1 fails - everything fails

Answer (score 7):

If you need to be able to handle each error individually then you'll have to append `catch()` (or maybe some other operator) to each Observable. Operators such as `forkJoin()` or `merge()` always send error notification when any of their sources send an error.

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

let sources = [
  Observable.of(123).catch((err) => Observable.of('caught error')),
  Observable.throw('error').catch((err) => Observable.of('caught error'))
];

Observable.forkJoin(...sources)
  .subscribe(values => console.log(values));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/hirodef/3/edit?js,console

The second Observable throws an error that is caught with `catch()` and replaced with `caught error` string.

This demo prints to console:

```
[123, "caught error"]
```